# Не работает генерация комментарий

Tags: c#, .net-7

Создал проект на платформе NET7

Ввожу в файле Programs.cs три слеша ///
И блок с комментариями не генерируется

Галочка на генерацию xml комментарий включена
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Включал отключал галочку, перезагружал ноутбук.

При старой конструкции проекта с классом и методом Main, генерирует, а когда пишешь в новой конструкции без класса программ и метода Main, не генерирует почему ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы что-то произошло, курсор надо поставить на одну строчку выше сигнатуры метода:

```
class Program
{
    |<-- вот сюда
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            
    }
}
```

Тогда при наборе `///` получится так:

```
class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            
    }
}
```

У меня работает из коробки, ничего не настраивал.

Над классами тоже работает:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            
    }
}
```

XML документация документирует API класса или библиотеки. Если у вас Top-level Statement, то как вы планируете его документировать, если даже `public` члены там объявить не можете?